# Excel previous month value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to fetch the last months value using excel formula

| Date | Product | current | Previous month value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Product A | 10 |  |
| Jan | Product B | 20 |  |
| Jan | Product C | 30 |  |
| Feb | Product A | 20 |  |
| Feb | Product B | 10 |  |
| Feb | Product C | 10 |  |

I need an excel formula to populate the previous month value to look like this

| Date | Product | current | Previous month value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Product A | 10 |  |
| Jan | Product B | 20 |  |
| Jan | Product C | 30 |  |
| Feb | Product A | 20 | 10 |
| Feb | Product B | 10 | 20 |
| Feb | Product C | 10 | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$8,($A$2:$A$8=TEXT(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1-"&A6&"-2024"),-1),"MMM"))*($B$2:$B$8=B6))
```

`TEXT`, `EOMONTH`, `DATEVALUE` to convert your text month to a date, and back to text.

`FILTER` to filter your current column by Date and Product.

[image]

If the values in column A are dates, the formula becomes easier:

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$8,($A$2:$A$8=EDATE(A6,-1))*($B$2:$B$8=B6))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks a ton for this solution. The date column is not necessarily text, i can also have date values(1/1/2024)  in the column instead of the text. In that case how would the formula be different?

Comment: Have added a second formula

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my company's excel version is 2016 and came to know filter function is only available from excel 2021. Is there an alternate to filter function for older version of excel?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no Excel Constraints then the following formula should work, however this is kind of assumption-based solution as there is no proper clarifications related with your post.*

The following formula uses single dynamic array formula, which effectively works with `Excel 2021+` onwards and gets updated whenever there is new entry :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2^5,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _data, A2:INDEX(A:C,_lastRow,),
     _date, DATE(2024,MONTH(INDEX(_data,,1)&0),1),
     XLOOKUP(EDATE(_date,-1)&"|"&INDEX(_data,,2),_date&"|"&INDEX(_data,,2),INDEX(_data,,3),0))
```

---